# Are there any API to integrate Microsoft exchange server with Java application for Task synchronization?

Tags: java, outlook, exchange-server

I am trying to integrate Java web application with Microsoft Exchange server for bi-directional calendar (i.e. Task) synchronization. Are there any Java Open-Source / Commercial API for this integration?

Thanks,
Venkat

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found this commercial API, offers quick solution to integrate with Exchange Server.
http://www.independentsoft.de/jwebservices/index.html

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at [j-Exchange](http://sourceforge.net/projects/j-xchange/) and [SyncEx](http://www.syncex.com/api/j2ee-java-api-exchange-domino.html).

This issue was once discussed on [Java Forums](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=608074&start=30)

Answer (score 6):

Microsoft made a new version of the Java APIs for Exchange 2007 and 2010.
It also has examples in the wiki.

https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-java-api

Answer (score 4):

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/exchangedev/archive/2010/12/14/exchange-web-services-java-api-1-1-is-now-available-yes-that-s-right-java.aspx

**Updated link:**

Exchange Web Services (EWS) Java API 1.2

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Exchange-EWS-Java-API-12-1a5a1143

Comment: ews-java-api pushed to github and the link is https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-java-api

Answer (score 0):

[JEC](http://www.javaexchangeconnector.com) is another Commercial API, It supports all Exchange versions, and as a bonus you can also run power shell, and Exchange Management Shell commands (via PSB)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CNS Media GateWay to synchronize your Exchange server with Java.

You can connect from any custom application like java to MS Exchange (2000 – 2013), MS SharePoint, Dynamics CRM, Dynamics NAV and many more via the CNS ODBC and JDBC driver, thus accessing, for example, the entire Exchange mailbox from your custom application.

Please let me know if you need some more information.

for more info visit:

http://www.connecting-software.com