# Exchange web services Kerberos Authentication

Tags: java, kerberos, exchangewebservices

I need to consume Exchange Web Services through Java Proxies generated by JAX-WS.

Can we connect to the Exchange server with Kerberos authentication?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1739921/are-there-any-api-to-integrate-microsoft-exchange-server-with-java-application-f

Answer (score 0):

Theres nothing specific to EWS in working with Kerberos. If you can call any web service with kerberos then you'll be able to call EWS.