# Is there any Java API to read Exchange Database or deleted mails in outlook mailbox?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, outlook, jakarta-mail, exchangewebservices

Now I'm creating an java app that have to retrieve deleted emails in outlook mailbox, I tried JavaMail API but seems it can only retrieve mails that exist in mailBox, so is there any way/Java APIs to read Exchange DB to retrieve those deleted mails? any suggestions or ideas are much appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to restore them out of the recycl bin, or fully deleted?

Comment: Do you have any ideas? Thanks for your attention.

Comment: @ user2659197 : you should contact administrator. There may be a backup copy/archived copies. In some cases, there are legal requirement to save all mails for quite some time.  You may ask this is in superuser/serverfault site

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1739921/are-there-any-api-to-integrate-microsoft-exchange-server-with-java-application-f/7517021#7517021

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft released a Java Api for exchange .

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/exchangedev/archive/2013/01/03/ews-java-api-1-2-get-started.aspx

From this API we can get the mails from any folder including deleted items,purges etc..,

**Sample code :**

```
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2007_SP1);
ExchangeCredentials credentials = new WebCredentials(userName, password);
service.setCredentials(credentials);
service.autodiscoverUrl(autoDiscoverUrl);
service.setTraceEnabled(true);

ItemView view = new ItemView(20);
FindItemsResults<Item> findResults;
do {
      findResults = service.findItems(WellKnownFolderName.RecoverableItemsDeletions, view);
      for (Item item : findResults.getItems()) {
        System.out.println(item);
      }
      view.setOffset(view.getOffset() + 20);
   } while (findResults.isMoreAvailable());
```

**WellKnownFolderName** enum contains all folders.

Comment: Thanks very much, it works fine for me. but why I cannot get any records using WellKnownFolderName.RecoverableItemsPurges as I have purged some mails in OutLook?

Comment: If you enable Litigation hold or In place preservation then only Purges folder contains mails. Otherwise exchange will delete the items, not move to purge folder. If you think this is answer mark it as answer.

Comment: Thanks very much!,one more question, if mails are fully deleted, are they archived into a folder of exchange server? How to find them?

Comment: That folders are not visible. Using power shell only we can view the count and details. There is no UI for that.

Comment: Thanks, So you mean we cannot access that folder via APIs, right? For the deleted mails, We can only access in Deletions or Purges folder?

Comment: If we delete any mail it will move to deleted items. From deleted items if we delete means it will move to recoverable items.From recoverable items if we delete means it will move to purges if Litigation hold or Inplace preservation is enabled. We can access all these folders via API.

Comment: But how to access mails that are deleted in purges if Litigation hold or Inplace preservation is enabled?

Comment: No we cannot access the mails deleted from purges.

Comment: Thanks! So any ways to access backup copy/archived copies of mails deleted from purges?