# Trying to read an account's inbox from MS exchange server using MAPI

Tags: java, email, outlook

I am trying to figure out an open source API which I can use in my java program to read unread mails from my inbox configured in MS Exchange server. If it would have been POP3 or IMAP to read mails from inbox, I could have used Javamail api. But unfortunately We use MAPI protocol.

Is there an open source API which can serve my purpose ?

(Note - my client is not open for any commercial api so moonrug and APIs like those are out of question)

Comment: There is no such thing as "MS outlook server". Do you mean Exchange Server?

Comment: Sorry Dmitry, 
 I understand outlook is just the client but I am not thinking straight right now. This specification is driving me nuts

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1739921/are-there-any-api-to-integrate-microsoft-exchange-server-with-java-application-f/7517021

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Exchange Web Services (which is pure HTTP) - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd877045(v=exchg.140).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the pointer Dmitry. Lemme figure out how to make it work and once it does, I will accept this answer as the correct one.

Comment: For all future loggers, Here's the solution to your problems :
Download EWSJavaAPI_1.2.jar and follow what ever the documentation says :)