# From where i can get EWS JAVA API 2.0?

Tags: java, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

Can anyone tell me from where I can get the EWS java API version 2.0.
I can find version 1.2 in github.

Basically I am  trying to connect to exchange server and retrieve the organization data like manager and his direct reports. With version 1.2 to and exchange serer 2007 SP3 its not supported.

IF any one has any better idea to perform this task let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Microsoft ever implemented it. Best you can do is pull the source for 1.2 and try to flesh it out yourself, though that looks to be a pain. (I'd love to be wrong on this one, though!)

Your other option is to go to a paid library. Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1739921/are-there-any-api-to-integrate-microsoft-exchange-server-with-java-application-f) for a good list of alternatives.