# EWS Java Api connecting to office 365

Tags: java, exchangewebservices

I am suppose to get calendar details in my code but I decided to check first if I could connect to outlook 365.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP1);//not sure if it should be SP1 or SP2
    ExchangeCredentials credentials = new WebCredentials("username@domain.com", "Redstorm#02");
    service.setCredentials(credentials);


    try {
        System.out.println("Check");
        service.setUrl(new URI("https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx"));
        service.setTraceEnabled(true);
        EmailMessage msg = new EmailMessage(service);
        msg.setSubject("Hello world!");
        msg.setBody(MessageBody.getMessageBodyFromText("Sent using the EWS Managed API."));
        msg.getToRecipients().add("username@domain.com");
        msg.send();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: i am having connection timed out errors. Please help me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1739921/are-there-any-api-to-integrate-microsoft-exchange-server-with-java-application-f/7517021

Answer (score 1):

I have had some issues with integrating my code with Office 365 too. Currently it seems to work for me using ews-java-api-2.0 jar built from the following URL:
[ews-java-api Github page](https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-java-api)

```
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.service.item.EmailMessage;
import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.ExchangeService;
import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.enumeration.misc.ExchangeVersion;
import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.credential.ExchangeCredentials;
import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.credential.WebCredentials;
import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.property.complex.MessageBody;

public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP2);
        ExchangeCredentials credentials = new WebCredentials("USERNAME@DOMAIN", "PASSWORD");
        service.setCredentials(credentials);
        try 
        {
            service.setUrl(new URI("https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx"));
            EmailMessage msg = new EmailMessage(service);
            msg.setSubject("Hello world!");
            msg.setBody(MessageBody.getMessageBodyFromText("Sent using the EWS Java API."));
            msg.getToRecipients().add("RECIPIENTMAIL@DOMAIN");
            msg.send();
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

I used Maven project for this test, here's my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>Test</groupId>
  <artifactId>Office365Test</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>Office365Test</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
        <version>4.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.4</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use the autodiscover service (and for Office365 use `Exchange2010_SP2`):

```
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP2);
ExchangeCredentials credentials = new WebCredentials("user@domain.com", "wont-tell-you");
service.setCredentials(credentials);
service.autodiscoverUrl("user@domain.com", 
        new IAutodiscoverRedirectionUrl() {
            @Override
            public boolean autodiscoverRedirectionUrlValidationCallback(String url) throws AutodiscoverLocalException {
                return url.toLowerCase().startsWith("https://");
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggention but I am having errorr : The Autodiscover service couldn't be located.

Comment: Did you check the credentials? Are you able to login into the WebUI?

Comment: yes i could login using my credentials in the web ui