# Using EWS to access OUTLOOK calender data

Tags: java, exchangewebservices

What is Exchange Web Services? How to use Exchange Web Services to access Outlook calendar data using Java?

Comment: "EWS, or Exchange Web Services, is a SOAP API that provide access to emails, contacts, appointments, tasks, and other Exchange Server data types and functionality. EWS was introduced with Exchange 2007 and is the primary extensibility API for Exchange Server and Exchange Online."

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1739921/are-there-any-api-to-integrate-microsoft-exchange-server-with-java-application-f/7517021#7517021

Answer (score 2):

You can view EWS as a library available from Microsoft to access Exchange Web Services. It's fairly easy and there are some nice tutorials on the Microsoft website.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj220499%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx

This should help you get started. Also this is for **c#** and **vb**. I don't know how you would use this in java, or even if you can. Good luck!