# Accessing Office 365 cloud from Java Application

Tags: office365, ewsjavaapi, outlook-restapi

could you please tell me difference between Office 365 REST API and EWS Java API.

I searched for Java library for REST API, but there is no library available.

We have written our application in Java so which way (REST API/Ews Java API)  we need to proceed for accessing office 365 cloud.

So now we don't have Java library for REST API , is it mandatory to use **Ews Java api** to sync contacts/emails/calendar and other stuff.

Is it recommend way to use Ews Java API for fetching office365 contacts/email/calendar

I raised one issue in ews java api two months back, still I didn't get any response from the them.

Could you suggest any reliable solution to use office365 API from Java application.

for using we need to register our app with Azure, can we resgiter for free or is it paid. If paid can you give us link for payment details , I didn't find anything.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1739921/are-there-any-api-to-integrate-microsoft-exchange-server-with-java-application-f

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exchange Web Services, or EWS, is a SOAP-based protocol for talking to Exchange. It works in Office 365, and there is the ews-java-api library on [GitHub](https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-java-api/). EWS can use basic authentication or OAuth, but to use OAuth you have to register your app in Azure AD (more on this below).

The Outlook REST APIs are REST-based and require OAuth. We recommend that you use these APIs if possible, but EWS will still work. There isn't a Java library for these APIs currently, but REST is a pretty standard protocol, so any generic Java REST library should work for invoking the API.

Registering an app is free, though currently it can be a little daunting. You need to have an Office 365 tenant and access to the Azure Management Portal. In order to get access to the portal, you do have to sign up for an Azure subscription. You can sign up for a "pay as you go" subscription, and access to your Office 365 Active Directory is free, so you never actually pay for anything. Here's a guide: https://github.com/jasonjoh/office365-azure-guides/blob/master/RegisterAnAppInAzure.md

We're working on enabling use of a personal Microsoft Account to register REST API apps which should make things much easier.