# Response didn't contain valid xml error in ews-java-api

Tags: java, exchangewebservices

I am trying to connect to my organization outlook account. Initially I was facing some error with autodiscover

```
The Autodiscover service couldn't be located
```

Therefore I commented out the line and used the url webservice url that is provided to me. But now I am getting the following error.

```
Exception in thread "main" microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.exception.service.remote.ServiceRequestException: The request failed. The response received from the service didn't contain valid XML.
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.request.SimpleServiceRequestBase.internalExecute(SimpleServiceRequestBase.java:74)
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.request.MultiResponseServiceRequest.execute(MultiResponseServiceRequest.java:158)
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.ExchangeService.internalCreateItems(ExchangeService.java:598)
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.ExchangeService.createItem(ExchangeService.java:657)
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.service.item.Item.internalCreate(Item.java:245)
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.service.item.EmailMessage.internalSend(EmailMessage.java:147)
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.service.item.EmailMessage.send(EmailMessage.java:258)
    at xxx.yyy.zzz.data.ExchangeMailReceiver.main(ExchangeMailReceiver.java:46)
Caused by: microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.exception.service.remote.ServiceRequestException: The response received from the service didn't contain valid XML.
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.request.ServiceRequestBase.readResponse(ServiceRequestBase.java:370)
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.request.SimpleServiceRequestBase.internalExecute(SimpleServiceRequestBase.java:63)
    ... 7 more
```

I am following what they have mentioned on their [github page](https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-java-api/wiki/Getting-Started-Guide)

This is the code that I am running

public class ExchangeMailReceiver {

```
static ExchangeService service = null;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String emailAddress = "myemailid";
    String password = "mypassword";

    service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP2);
    ExchangeCredentials credentials = new WebCredentials(emailAddress, password);
    service.setCredentials(credentials);

    service.setUrl(new URI("https://xxx.yyy.zzz/owa/auth/logon.aspx?"));

//      try {
//          service.autodiscoverUrl(emailAddress, new RedirectionUrlCallback());
//      } catch (Exception e) {
//          e.printStackTrace();
//      }

    findChildFolders();
}

public static void findChildFolders() throws Exception {
    FindFoldersResults findResults = service.findFolders(
            WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, new FolderView(Integer.MAX_VALUE));

    for (Folder folder : findResults.getFolders()) {
        System.out.println("Count======" + folder.getChildFolderCount());
        System.out.println("Name=======" + folder.getDisplayName());
    }
}

class RedirectionUrlCallback implements IAutodiscoverRedirectionUrl {
    public boolean autodiscoverRedirectionUrlValidationCallback(
            String redirectionUrl) {
        return redirectionUrl.toLowerCase().startsWith("https://");
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1739921/are-there-any-api-to-integrate-microsoft-exchange-server-with-java-application-f/7517021