# How to connect to exchange web services via java servlet

Tags: java, servlets, exchangewebservices

I am trying to connect to EWS using the java API by using the java servlet.

I have created the servlet and it is working fine (set some prints to the console). Also made a bridge from PHP to the servlet. Then I've added the java EWS jar file to my build path, ran some function from the API and got the following stack trace error. (I must say that i am new at working with java servlets).

```
Warning: Unchecked exception detected: 

[[o:Response$UndeclaredThrowableErrorMarker]:"FATAL: Undeclared java.lang.RuntimeException detected. java.lang.Exception: Invoke failed: [[o:Main]]->goodBye. Cause: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Unresolved external reference: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/config/Lookup. -- Unable to call the method, see the README section "Java platform issues" for details and DO NOT REPORT THIS PROBLEM TO THE PHP/Java Bridge MAILING LIST! VM: 1.7.0_91@http://java.o[...]k/testphpjava/Java.inc(560): java_Client->getResult()
#4 /storage/work/testphpjava/Java.inc(1752): java_Client->invokeMethod(2, 'goodBye', Array)
#5 /storage/work/testphpjava/Java.inc(1851): java_JavaProxy->__call('goodBye', Array)
#6 /storage/work/testphpjava/Java.inc(1999): java_AbstractJava->__call('goodBye', Array)
#7 /storage/work/testphpjava/test.php(6): Java->__call('goodBye', Array)
#8 /storage/work/testphpjava/test.php(6): java_InternalJava->goodBye()
#9 {main}] in /storage/work/testphpjava/Java.inc on line 202
[[o:Response$UndeclaredThrowableErrorMarker]:"FATAL: Undeclared java.lang.RuntimeException detected. java.lang.Exception: Invoke failed: [[o:Main]]->goodBye. Cause: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Unresolved external reference: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/config/Lookup. -- Unable to call the method, see the README section "Java platform issues" for details and DO NOT REPORT THIS PROBLEM TO THE PHP/Java Bridge MAILING LIST! VM: 1.7.0_91@http://java.oracle.com/" at:
#-21 php.java.bridge.JavaBridge.getUnresolvedExternalReferenceException(JavaBridge.java:422)
#-20 php.java.bridge.JavaBridge.Invoke(JavaBridge.java:1055)
#-19 php.java.bridge.Request.handleRequest(Request.java:417)
#-18 php.java.bridge.Request.handleRequests(Request.java:500)
#-17 php.java.bridge.JavaBridge.handleRequests(JavaBridge.java:150)
#-16 php.java.servlet.RemoteHttpServletContextFactory.handleRequests(RemoteHttpServletContextFactory.java:262)
#-15 ews.Main.doPut(Main.java:58)
#-14 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
#-13 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
#-12 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
#-11 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
#-10 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
#-9 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
#-8 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
#-7 org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
#-6 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
#-5 org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
#-4 org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
#-3 org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
#-2 org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
#-1 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
#0 /storage/work/testphpjava/Java.inc(232): java_ThrowExceptionProxyFactory->getProxy(3, 'ews.Main', 'F', true)
#1 /storage/work/testphpjava/Java.inc(360): java_Arg->getResult(true)
#2 /storage/work/testphpjava/Java.inc(366): java_Client->getWrappedResult(true)
#3 /storage/work/testphpjava/Java.inc(560): java_Client->getResult()
#4 /storage/work/testphpjava/Java.inc(1752): java_Client->invokeMethod(2, 'goodBye', Array)
#5 /storage/work/testphpjava/Java.inc(1851): java_JavaProxy->__call('goodBye', Array)
#6 /storage/work/testphpjava/Java.inc(1999): java_AbstractJava->__call('goodBye', Array)
#7 /storage/work/testphpjava/test.php(6): Java->__call('goodBye', Array)
#8 /storage/work/testphpjava/test.php(6): java_InternalJava->goodBye()
#9 {main}]
Fatal error: An unchecked exception occured during script execution. Please check the server log files for details. in /storage/work/testphpjava/Java.inc on line 776
```

appreciate your help.

Comment: You probably need to include the apache httpcomponents core jar. http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpcore

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1739921/are-there-any-api-to-integrate-microsoft-exchange-server-with-java-application-f/7517021