# What does `A1 NO AUTHENTICATE failed` error message mean when trying to read e-mails via IMAP?

Tags: java, exchange-server, imap

I have following code which is supposed to open a connection to a Microsoft Exchange server via IMAP:

```
        Folder inputFolder = null;
        Folder doneFolder = null;
        Store store = null;
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        Session emailSession = null;

        properties.put("mail.imaps.host", imapHost);
        properties.put("mail.imaps.user", mailUsername);
        properties.put("mail.imaps.port", Integer.toString(imapPort));
        properties.put("mail.imaps.starttls.enable", "true");

        MailSSLSocketFactory sf = new MailSSLSocketFactory();
        sf.setTrustedHosts(new String[]{"XXXXXXXXX"});
        properties.put("mail.imaps.socketFactory", sf);
        properties.put("mail.debug", "true");

        logger.info(String.format("Using user name '%s'", mailUsername));

        try {
            emailSession = createEmailSession(properties);
            store = getStore(emailSession);
            store.connect(mailUsername, mailPassword);
```

`XXXXXXXXX` is the host name.

`createEmailSession` and `getStore` methods look like this:

```
    Store getStore(final Session emailSession) throws NoSuchProviderException {
        return emailSession.getStore("imaps");
    }

    Session createEmailSession(final Properties properties) {
        return Session.getInstance(properties);
    }
```

`store.connect(mailUsername, mailPassword)` leads to following error message:

```
Caused by: javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: AUTHENTICATE failed.
                at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:732)
                at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:366)
                at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:246)
                at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:267)
```

Debug output looks like this:

```
DEBUG: JavaMail version 1.6.2
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.address.map
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Oracle]
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.fetchsize: 16384
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.ignorebodystructuresize: false
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.statuscachetimeout: 1000
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.appendbuffersize: -1
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.minidletime: 10
DEBUG IMAPS: enable STARTTLS
DEBUG IMAPS: closeFoldersOnStoreFailure
DEBUG IMAPS: trying to connect to host "XXXXXXXXX", port 993, isSSL true
* OK The Microsoft Exchange IMAP4 service is ready.
A0 CAPABILITY
* CAPABILITY IMAP4 IMAP4rev1 AUTH=PLAIN SASL-IR UIDPLUS MOVE ID UNSELECT CHILDREN IDLE NAMESPACE LITERAL+
A0 OK CAPABILITY completed.
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTH: PLAIN
DEBUG IMAPS: protocolConnect login, host=XXXXXXXXX, user=YYYYYYYYY, password=<non-null>
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTHENTICATE PLAIN command trace suppressed
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTHENTICATE PLAIN command result: A1 NO AUTHENTICATE failed.
DEBUG IMAPS: IMAPStore cleanup, not connected
```

The credentials (`YYYYYYYYY` and corresponding password) used to work. Then I started to get messages like this. I talked with the admin and they told me that the user was locked due to too many attempts to login with the wrong password. They also said that they unlocked the user and it should work now.

But it doesn't.

Based on the debug output above, how can I narrow down the problem?

**Update 1:** According to [this](https://getadmx.com/?Category=Office2016&Policy=outlk16.Office.Microsoft.Policies.Windows::L_AuthenticationwithExchangeServer) page, Exchange server only supports Kerberos and NTLM authentication, while I am using `PLAIN`. Maybe this is the reason why it fails.

**Update 2:** [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36725506/399457) suggests using [ews-java-api](https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-java-api) for accessing Exchange Server. Will try it out.

**Update 3:** Suppressing plain text authentication using

```
properties.put("mail.imap.auth.plain.disable", "true");
```

did not help.

Comment: They disabled PLAIN at the start of October. Anything that transmits passwords will not get a NO response, which means that the command was correct and understandable and so on, but failed. Your best path forward is to use oauth, like on gmail.

Comment: @arnt Thanks. If you know about any documentation or code samples for this, please post a link here.

Comment: @arnt Also, is there any other authentication method other than OAuth?

Comment: Yours is not the first question about this, so browse the older questions, there are links there. I even think I've answered this personally. And yes, there are others, but I'm too busy to google this now. Sorry.

Comment: The thing is, sometimes it does work